# Close dialog moves under navbar (close button may no longer be available)

Tags: bug, new-nav

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot above, if I move the close dialog around it goes under the toplevel navbar, and it can be moved in a way that the [X] button to close the popup is no longer reachable.

The pop up dialog should be always at the foremost Z position.

Comment: *if I move the close dialog around* don't ... just don't ...

Comment: @rene Why? Sometimes I need it to get out of the way to read something in the question again. :-)

Comment: You can always click outside the popup to close it.

Comment: @Andre Ah, I didn't notice that so far.